# How to remove quotation marks from innerHTML output

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

Good Day. I am facing a bit of a problem and I would appreciate your assistance

I am trying to create a JS code that will save information into localStorage then display the saved information into a new div...

It is working but the information returns in inverted commas and I would like to know if there is a way to remove them.

*HTML*

````
<div id = "dateHead" > Date : </div>

<div id ="incJobs></div>

*JAVASCRIPT*

var dateHead = document.getElementById("dateHead").innerHTML;


localStorage.setItem("jobInfo", JSON.stringify(dateHead));

var storedInfo = localStorage.getItem("jobInfo

document.getElementById("incJobs").innerHTML = storedInfo;```

It returns : "Date :"



I plan on including input tags which is the reason I'm saving it to localStorage

Thank You.
````

Comment: And please fix the [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and the syntax error in your JS.

Comment: Hi Khibak, keep editing until it look right

Comment: you all beating a new user down before he's finished editing, not nice all was noobs once

Comment: So you are trying to store html inside localstorage and again trying to append it to another div. Is that your end goal? Then, use JSON.parse while appending the text to div.

Comment: document.getElementById("incJobs").innerHTML = JSON.Parse(storedInfo);

Comment: I actually want to do the same thing with input tags...

Answer (score 1):

`<div id ="incJobs"></div>`
You didn't add the last  inverted comma in this div tag's ID